# How to show $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_1)\preceq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_i)$?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics, inequalities

> Let two collections of random variables $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ be independent and let $\{Y_i\}$ be i.i.d. Then
>   $$\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_1)\preceq \max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_i).$$
>   where $\preceq$ is stochastic domination.

I think it needs to find a coupling such that $X_i'=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_1)$ and $Y_i'=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(X_i+Y_i)$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_i'<Y_i')$...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @IosifPinelis How to prove this statement?

Comment: @DieterKadelka   Your $Y_i$ are not i.i.d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditioning on the $X_i$'s and using the independence of the $Y_i$'s from the $X_i$'s, we reduce the consideration to the case when $X_i=x_i$ for some real $x_i$'s and all $i$. So, the statement of interest reduces to this: 
$$P(x_i+Y_1\le y\quad \forall i)\ge P(x_i+Y_i\le y\quad \forall i)$$
for all real $y$, 
which can be rewritten as 
$$F(y-\max_i x_i)\ge\prod_i F(y-x_i)$$
where $F$ is the cdf of each $Y_i$. But the latter inequality obviously holds, since $\max_i x_i=x_j$ for some $j$ whereas $0\le F\le1$.

Comment: @BobO. : Everything seems correct as written in the answer. The expression $P(\max_i x_i+Y_1\le y\quad \forall i)$ in your comment does not seem to make much sense. However, $P(x_i+Y_1\le y\quad \forall i)=P(\max_ix_i+Y_1\le y)=P(Y_1\le y-\max_ix_i)=F(y-\max_ix_i)$.

Comment: Thanks so much.